# Merging String[] in Java

Tags: java

What is the best way to merge muliple String[] into a single String[] in Java?

Comment: What is your definition of "best"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another possibility:

```
public static String[] mergeStrings(String[]...matrix){
    int total = 0;
       for(String[] vector : matrix){
             total += vector.length;
       }
       String[] resp = new String[total];

       for(int i=0; i< matrix.length; i++){
           for(int j=0; j< matrix[i].length; j++){
                resp[i*matrix.length + j] = matrix[i][j];
           }
       }
       return resp;
}
```

you cant test with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] resp =mergeStrings(new String[]{"1","2"}, new String[]{"3", "4", "5"});
        for(String s : resp)
            System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, you would make a single [] that is equal to the size of all the [] together, and then call System.arraycopy

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object, int, java.lang.Object, int, int

to move each guy to the new big array.

This would be o(n), where n is the number of strings you want to combine.

The better question is, is your code really so performance critical that you use array over arrayList?  ArrayList is much easier to work with and should be used over [] in most cases.

Comment: I have to give an String[] to an API that I haven't written myself.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to use [`System#arraycopy()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) instead which is doing platform native operation (and thus yields better performance):

```
public static String[] concat(String[]... arrays) {
    int length = 0;
    for (String[] array : arrays) {
        length += array.length;
    }
    String[] newArray = new String[length];
    int pos = 0;
    for (String[] array : arrays) {
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArray, pos, array.length);
        pos += array.length;
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

More generified:

```
public static <T> T[] concat(Class<T> type, T[]... arrays) {
    int length = 0;
    for (T[] array : arrays) {
        length += array.length;
    }
    T[] newArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, length);
    int pos = 0;
    for (T[] array : arrays) {
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArray, pos, array.length);
        pos += array.length;
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Usage examples:

```
String[] arr1 = { "foo1", "bar1" };
String[] arr2 = { "foo2", "bar2", "baz2" };
String[] arr3 = { "foo3" };

String[] all1 = concat(arr1, arr2, arr3);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(all1)); // [foo1, bar1, foo2, bar2, baz2, foo3]

String[] all2 = concat(String.class, arr1, arr2, arr3);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(all2)); // [foo1, bar1, foo2, bar2, baz2, foo3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use java.util.Arrays to create a collection and then back to List :)

```
    String[] moo1 = {"moo", "moo2"};
    String[] moo2 = {"moo3", "moo4"};
    String[] moo3 = {"moo5", "moo5"};

    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    strings.addAll(Arrays.asList(moo1));
    strings.addAll(Arrays.asList(moo2));
    strings.addAll(Arrays.asList(moo3));
    String[] array = strings.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: The `Arrays#asList()` in your code would return `List<String[]>`, not `List<String>` as you seem to expect.

Comment: Better, but I'd prefer `System#arrayCopy()` :) (I didn't downvote btw).